# How do I reset Magento Admin User Role

Tags: magento2, magento-1.8, admin, user-roles

I went into Admin->System->Permission->Roles & edit the role for Admin

Now, i am unable to re-set back it to original "ALL" permissions.

How can i revert back to original settings ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you do, do not delete the Magento stock **Admin User** account, much irritation ensues. As you're finding, messing with its **Role ACL** also has future repercussions.

The usual method is to use a script to create a new admin account with full access so you can repair the old account and reset the ACL to All.

I don't plan on plagiarizing work done by Inchoo, so this will be a linked answer: [Locked out from Magento Admin](http://inchoo.net/magento/locked-out-from-magento-admin/)

Reported to work with up to 1.8.1.0

Use mysqldump to back up your database before doing anything further.

Answer (score 2):

*[ Magento 2.x.x ]*

Yes I also done this When I make First time in Module acl.xml and I was check it whether it works or not.

**I try to create a Admin user one, two , three....  and no Admin user access, because I remove All Administrators's Role.**

then I done Below thing to get All Admin user's Role ( Reset Role ).

***Note:- use mysqldump to back up your databases before doing anything further***

Step-1: Back up below Tables

```
    Table 1 :-  admin_user
    
    Table 2 :-  authorization_role
    
    Table 3 :-  authorization_rule
```

Step-2: truncate Above three Table using truncate command ( not using DELETE command )

```
truncate table [ Table Name ];
```

Step-3: insert new User in with All Roles , Run below three Command

1. This insert data into admin_user table

   ```
        INSERT INTO `admin_user` (`user_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `username`, `password`, `created`, `modified`, `logdate`, `lognum`, `reload_acl_flag`, `is_active`, `extra`, `rp_token`, `rp_token_created_at`, `interface_locale`, `failures_num`, `first_failure`, `lock_expires`, `refresh_token`) VALUES (1, 'admin', 'admin', 'admin@gmail.com', 'admin', '45cf9053530ceb9fde49794d9e6d81fd2ce481b0136067986a5c9bc139a7d08f:FivE4hOQqPtW1xdE:2', '2019-07-23 10:48:31', '2019-09-09 13:20:42', '2019-09-09 13:20:42', 46, 0, 1, '{\"configState\":{\"contact_contact\":\"1\",\"web_default_layouts\":\"0\",\"web_default\":\"1\",\"web_secure\":\"1\",\"web_seo\":\"1\",\"web_unsecure\":\"1\",\"wishlist_wishlist_link\":\"1\",\"wishlist_email\":\"1\",\"wishlist_general\":\"1\",\"admin_emails\":\"0\",\"admin_startup\":\"0\",\"dev_front_end_development_workflow\":\"1\",\"dev_restrict\":\"0\",\"dev_debug\":\"1\",\"dev_template\":\"0\",\"sw_megamenu_general\":\"1\",\"newsletter_general\":\"1\",\"newsletter_subscription\":\"1\",\"dev_js\":\"0\",\"admin_security\":\"0\",\"admin_url\":\"0\",\"admin_dashboard\":\"0\",\"admin_captcha\":\"0\",\"sw_megamenu_custom_links\":\"1\",\"sw_megamenu_cat_labels\":\"1\",\"cms_wysiwyg\":\"1\",\"catalog_frontend\":\"1\",\"catalog_fields_masks\":\"0\",\"catalog_review\":\"1\",\"catalog_productalert\":\"1\",\"catalog_productalert_cron\":\"1\",\"catalog_placeholder\":\"1\",\"catalog_recently_products\":\"1\",\"catalog_product_video\":\"0\",\"catalog_price\":\"0\",\"catalog_layered_navigation\":\"1\",\"catalog_search\":\"0\",\"catalog_seo\":\"0\",\"catalog_navigation\":\"1\",\"catalog_downloadable\":\"1\",\"catalog_custom_options\":\"0\",\"layered_navigation_module\":\"1\",\"layered_navigation_general\":\"1\",\"carriers_flatrate\":\"1\",\"carriers_freeshipping\":\"1\",\"carriers_tablerate\":\"1\",\"carriers_temando\":\"1\",\"carriers_ups\":\"1\",\"carriers_usps\":\"1\",\"carriers_fedex\":\"1\",\"carriers_dhl\":\"1\",\"shipping_origin\":\"1\",\"shipping_shipping_policy\":\"1\",\"tax_vertex_settings\":\"1\",\"tax_classes\":\"1\",\"tax_calculation\":\"1\",\"tax_defaults\":\"1\",\"tax_display\":\"1\",\"tax_cart_display\":\"1\",\"tax_sales_display\":\"1\",\"tax_weee\":\"1\",\"tax_vertex_seller_info\":\"0\",\"tax_vertex_delivery_terms\":\"0\",\"tax_avaiable_shipping_product_codes\":\"0\",\"tax_vertex_logging\":\"0\",\"dev_grid\":\"0\",\"dev_static\":\"0\",\"dev_image\":\"0\",\"dev_css\":\"0\",\"dev_translate_inline\":\"0\",\"general_store_information\":\"1\",\"general_single_store_mode\":\"1\",\"general_locale\":\"1\",\"general_region\":\"1\",\"general_country\":\"1\",\"productinquiry_general_option\":\"1\",\"productinquiry_google_captcha\":\"1\",\"productinquiry_email_setting\":\"1\",\"trans_email_ident_general\":\"1\",\"product_attachment_general\":\"1\",\"product_attachment_display_configuration\":\"1\"}}', NULL, NULL, 'en_US', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   ```
2. This insert Data into authorization_role table

   INSERT INTO `authorization_role` (`role_id`, `parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `user_type`, `role_name`) VALUES
   (1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, '2', 'Administrators'),
   (2, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 1, '2', 'admin');
3. This insert Data into authorization_rule

   INSERT INTO `authorization_rule` (`rule_id`, `role_id`, `resource_id`, `privileges`, `permission`) VALUES
   (1, 1, 'Magento_Backend::all', NULL, 'allow');

Step-4: Run below Magento Command

```
    php bin/magento set:up;
    
    php bin/magento s:s:d -f ;
    
    php bin/magento c:f ;
    
    php bin/magento c:c ;
```

Step-5: Run your Admin login and try below username and password to login.

```
    username :- admin
    
    Password :- admin@123
```

if above username and password not working please create new admin user [click here](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-add-admin-user-command-line.html)

Now your Administrators Role are Reset to default.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: if you have any doubt to above process related you can comment here

Comment: and next time you have to create another user role which have same as a admin role but not a exactly same to same role for next time this problem not create

Comment: You saved me a lot of time, and I just wanted to say Thank You <3