# How to Reset Magento Admin Permission

Tags: magento2, admin, user-roles, rules

Admin role have no permissions, when I log in I just see only a extensions. How to reset permission in database MAGENTO 2 version?

Comment: try to access your database and go to  `authorization_role` table, see your role name and update value for `parent_id` to be `1`. hope this works

Comment: Did you try with this soluton? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124429/33057

Comment: I did it but still same. I called hosting service and they uploaded database backup. No problem now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

*[ Magento 2.x.x ]*

Yes I also done this When I make First time in Module acl.xml and I was check it whether it works or not.

**I try to create a Admin user one, two , three....  and no Admin user access, because I remove All Administrators's Role.**

then I done Below thing to get All Admin user's Role ( Reset Role ).

***Note:- use mysqldump to back up your databases before doing anything further***

Step-1: Back up below Tables

```
    Table 1 :-  admin_user
    
    Table 1 :-  authorization_role
    
    Table 1 :-  authorization_rule
```

Step-2: truncate Above three Table using truncate command ( not using DELETE command )

```
truncate table [ Table Name ];
```

Step-3: insert new User in with All Roles , Run below three Command

1. This insert data into admin_user table

   INSERT INTO `admin_user` (`user_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `username`, `password`, `created`, `modified`, `logdate`, `lognum`, `reload_acl_flag`, `is_active`, `extra`, `rp_token`, `rp_token_created_at`, `interface_locale`, `failures_num`, `first_failure`, `lock_expires`, `refresh_token`) VALUES
   (1, 'admin', 'admin', 'admin@gmail.com', 'admin', '45cf9053530ceb9fde49794d9e6d81fd2ce481b0136067986a5c9bc139a7d08f:FivE4hOQqPtW1xdE:2', '2019-07-23 10:48:31', '2019-09-09 13:20:42', '2019-09-09 13:20:42', 46, 0, 1, '{"configState":{"contact_contact":"1","web_default_layouts":"0","web_default":"1","web_secure":"1","web_seo":"1","web_unsecure":"1","wishlist_wishlist_link":"1","wishlist_email":"1","wishlist_general":"1","admin_emails":"0","admin_startup":"0","dev_front_end_development_workflow":"1","dev_restrict":"0","dev_debug":"1","dev_template":"0","sw_megamenu_general":"1","newsletter_general":"1","newsletter_subscription":"1","dev_js":"0","admin_security":"0","admin_url":"0","admin_dashboard":"0","admin_captcha":"0","sw_megamenu_custom_links":"1","sw_megamenu_cat_labels":"1","cms_wysiwyg":"1","catalog_frontend":"1","catalog_fields_masks":"0","catalog_review":"1","catalog_productalert":"1","catalog_productalert_cron":"1","catalog_placeholder":"1","catalog_recently_products":"1","catalog_product_video":"0","catalog_price":"0","catalog_layered_navigation":"1","catalog_search":"0","catalog_seo":"0","catalog_navigation":"1","catalog_downloadable":"1","catalog_custom_options":"0","layered_navigation_module":"1","layered_navigation_general":"1","carriers_flatrate":"1","carriers_freeshipping":"1","carriers_tablerate":"1","carriers_temando":"1","carriers_ups":"1","carriers_usps":"1","carriers_fedex":"1","carriers_dhl":"1","shipping_origin":"1","shipping_shipping_policy":"1","tax_vertex_settings":"1","tax_classes":"1","tax_calculation":"1","tax_defaults":"1","tax_display":"1","tax_cart_display":"1","tax_sales_display":"1","tax_weee":"1","tax_vertex_seller_info":"0","tax_vertex_delivery_terms":"0","tax_avaiable_shipping_product_codes":"0","tax_vertex_logging":"0","dev_grid":"0","dev_static":"0","dev_image":"0","dev_css":"0","dev_translate_inline":"0","general_store_information":"1","general_single_store_mode":"1","general_locale":"1","general_region":"1","general_country":"1","productinquiry_general_option":"1","productinquiry_google_captcha":"1","productinquiry_email_setting":"1","trans_email_ident_general":"1","product_attachment_general":"1","product_attachment_display_configuration":"1"}}', NULL, NULL, 'en_US', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
2. This insert Data into authorization_role table

   INSERT INTO `authorization_role` (`role_id`, `parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `user_type`, `role_name`) VALUES
   (1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, '2', 'Administrators'),
   (2, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 1, '2', 'admin');
3. This insert Data into authorization_rule

   INSERT INTO `authorization_rule` (`rule_id`, `role_id`, `resource_id`, `privileges`, `permission`) VALUES
   (1, 1, 'Magento_Backend::all', NULL, 'allow');

Step-4: Run below Magento Command

```
    php bin/magento set:up;
    
    php bin/magento s:s:d -f ;
    
    php bin/magento c:f ;
    
    php bin/magento c:c ;
```

Step-5: Run your Admin login and try below username and password to login.

```
    username :- admin
    
    Password :- admin@123
```

If above user not working create an new admin user in terminal [click here](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-add-admin-user-command-line.html)

Now your Administrators Role are Reset to default.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: and next time you have to create another user role which have same as a admin role but not a exactly same to same role for next time this problem not create

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding this because like me you have accidentally removed your permissions to update your admin user account role's permissions and are now locked out of your account, use this query in the DB to reset the permissions for your role:

```
UPDATE authorization_rule SET permission = "allow" WHERE role_id = 1
```

You have to switch the role_id with your current role's ID of course.