# No Administrators role was found, data fixture needs to be run

Tags: magento2, database, cli

am trying to create an admin user from the CLI while running the commands I get the following error:-

```
# php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=pramod --admin-password=pramod@123 --admin-email=pramod.mishra@netsmartz.net --admin-firstname=pramod --admin-lastname=mishra
```

**In AdminAccount.php line 262:**

No Administrators role was found, data fixture needs to be run

[image: No Administrators role was found, data fixture needs to be run]

How to fix it? Any idea thanks

**Update:**

I have a new error now while logging in to admin.

More permissions are needed to access this.

Comment: Please try this https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2/issues/351


 INSERT INTO authorization_rule (rule_id, role_id, resource_id, privileges, permission) VALUES (1, 1, 'Magento_Backend::all', null, 'allow');

Comment: Please try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/290450/82670

Answer (score 6):

The error is caused because your database isn't complete, I had the same issue by creating a DB dump via Magerun 2 using the param `--strip=@development`.

Your `authorization_role` and `authorization_role` database tables are probably empty.

**How to fix**

Create a authorized admin role and rule.

```
INSERT INTO authorization_role (role_id, parent_id, tree_level, sort_order, role_type, user_id, user_type, role_name) VALUES (1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, '2', 'Administrators');
INSERT INTO authorization_rule (rule_id, role_id, resource_id, privileges, permission) VALUES (1, 1, 'Magento_Backend::all', null, 'allow');
```

And delete all your previous admin users in your local environment.

```
DELETE FROM admin_user;
```

Answer (score 1):

For creating a new administrator account for Magento 2 we use the Magento CLI.
Hope this helpful for you.

1. Login into your Magento 2 Server with SSH

   ssh your-username@$your-server-ip
2. Navigate to the Magento 2 directory e.g.

/home/cloudpanel/htdocs/magento2.com/
3) Execute the following command in order to create a new administrator with username "new-admin" and password "!admin123!"

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='new-admin' --admin-password='!admin123!' --admin-email='info@domain.com' --admin-firstname='Jon' --admin-lastname='Doe'
```

Once the new Magento 2 administrator account has been created, you will see the following success message:

Created Magento administrator user named new-admin

```
Parameter explanation
Name    Value
--admin-user    Magento administrator user name
--admin-password    Magento administrator user password
--admin-email   Magento administrator user's e-mail address
--admin-firstname   Magento administrator user's first name
--admin-lastname    Magento administrator user's last name
```

To see all available options you can execute the following command

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --help
```

For The role

```
INSERT INTO authorization_role (role_id, parent_id, tree_level, sort_order, role_type, user_id, user_type, role_name) VALUES (1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, '2', 'Administrators');
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the Admin role in the table was set to "Administrator" instead of "Administrators".

So I changed it directly in the database and now it works.