# Sorry, you need permissions to view this content

Tags: magento2, permissions, user-roles, admin-user

I have created a admin user by below command.

`php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin1" --admin-password="admin@123" --admin-email="admin1@gmail.com" --admin-firstname="fname" --admin-lastname="lname"`

Now, Admin is login successfully but I do not have permission for anything in admin. Below is the Error.

**Sorry, you need permissions to view this content.**
Please help me how can I solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2.4.0 has the 2FA ACL incorrectly configured, so you must allocate both the following ACL to all non Admin "All" roles:

```
System > Permissions > Two Factor Auth
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Two Factor Auth
```

With these ACL's in place user can set their own 2FA and will not be met with the "Sorry, you need permissions to view this content" error.". This is a M 2.4.0 bug and fixed in later versions.

Note users with "Stores > Settings > Configuration > Two Factor Auth" ACL can disabled 2FA for all users once logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Check your module's acl.xml file for error & then do setup upgrade.
If issue still persists then comment code in acl.xml file & then do setup upgrade. Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

this issue is related to admin created user access. it is occurs if user try to access unauthorised resources
i suggest you to do the following  two things

1) check your acl.xml file and provide access to the resource from backend using administrator credencials navigate to system>>user roles>>resources and checked the recource option

2) remove/comment the _isAllowed() method  body from controller file.
like below.

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_ModuleName::Resource');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some other things that you can have to do to have access again.

As far as I know, if you do not have access to the back-office, you will not be able to change permission for the new user.

In that case, you will need to do plain sql modifications as explained in this post : [Reset roles for Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124428/how-do-i-reset-administrator-role-permissions)

If you have access with another user to the back-office, go to [Magento documentation about admin users](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/permissions-user-roles.html) and follow instructions for the user with restricted access. It will unlock the permission for the other user.

Comment: Thanks @Christophe
I have try with your suggested  URL(Reset roles for Magento 2) but it's not working for me.

Comment: Can you please provide me with the queries you've made ? Update your question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently done your Magento setup and facing this issue,

Clear all the cache and generated folder. Please let me know if this works, thank you!

```
rm -rf var/* generated/*
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no code to check if the 2FA is enabled or not. In Magento2.4.2 it is allowed by default.
To correct this I have done some changes and these are working for me.

1. Magento\TwoFactorAuth\Observer\ControllerActionPredispatch.php

> Add below code in execute() method
>
> ```
> public function execute(Observer $observer)
>        {
>
>            if (!$this->tfa->isEnabled()) {
>                return;
>            }
> ```

2. Magento\TwoFactorAuth\Model\Tfa.php

> change
>
> ```
> public function isEnabled(): bool
>    {
>        return true;
>    }
>
>
>    to
>
>   
> public function isEnabled(): bool
>    {
>        return !!$this->scopeConfig->getValue(TfaInterface::XML_PATH_ENABLED);
>    }
> ```

3. Added in file vendor\magento\module-two-factor-auth\Api\TfaInterface.php

> const XML_PATH_ENABLED = 'twofactorauth/general/enabled';

After these changes, if you disable the 2FA then it will bypass this

Answer (score 0):

1.In your phpmyadmin,update the AUTHORIZATION_RULE table.It will show "deny" text in all the Permissions column.
[image]
2. In that table,Run this query to solve the issue.
UPDATE `authorization_rule` SET `permission`='allow'

3.Do the Cache flush in magento root directory and check your admin panel.